# How to set the time in 00:00:00 for same values contain in same column using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with one input with time and date. Here I want to convert the time contain in same values in same column into 00:00:00

Here I wrote the code it is just given me on start time per day for same value. If I had two same values in one day, it is not showing time as 00:00:00. It is just showing NaN value.

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                        format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = df['x3'].eq(5)
df['Duration'] = (df[mask].drop_duplicates(['date','x3'])
                      .groupby(['date','x3'])['time_diff']
                      .transform('first'))
df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
```

output be like :

```html
date time                x3      duration
10/3/2018 6:15:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 6:45:00         5 00:00:00
10/3/2018 7:45:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 9:00:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 9:25:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 9:30:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 11:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 13:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5 NaN
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 15:25:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 16:25:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 19:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 19:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 22:05:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5 NaN
10/3/2018 23:40:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 6:58:00         5 00:00:00
10/4/2018 13:00:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0 NaN
```

But I expected output is:

```html
date   time        x3 duration
10/3/2018 6:15:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 6:45:00   5 00:00:00 
10/3/2018 7:45:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 9:00:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 9:25:00         0       NaN
10/3/2018 9:30:00         0 NaN
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 11:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 13:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5 00:00:00
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 15:25:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 16:25:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 19:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 19:30:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 22:05:00 0 NaN
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5 00:00:00
10/3/2018 23:40:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 6:58:00         5 00:00:00
10/4/2018 13:00:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0 NaN
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0 NaN
```

my csv file :

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this should work.

```
df['Duration'] = np.where(df['x3']== 5, df['time_diff'], np.datetime64('NaT') )
df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
```

Comment: @Yes I tried it earlier and it gave me difference in between these same value. "0.0, 7.05hr" like that

Comment: That is because there is a difference between times. if you remove the last line 'df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)`. it may work. Without the original data, it is difficult to replicate the problem.

Comment: No it is not working. Here I posted my csv file. You may can look at my original data .

Comment: @ SH-SF Yes now it worked. Thank you very much for the answer